# What is the correct word for people for which you buy insurance?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am thinking of the word "Co-insured" but I'm not sure.

E.g. when you pay for some insurance for yourself and your family. Your daughter does not pay but she is covered. She's a ...

Comment: co-insured is not the word you are looking for.  Co-insured is when you are paying and someone else is paying and you get covered by both policies.  Dependent is the word you are looking for.

Comment: For health insurance she would be a *listed/covered dependent*.  In short, she would be ***covered***.  But if I were to just pay your car insurance for you, there's no special insurance term for that.

Comment: Every person covered by an insurance policy is a covered party, an insured, an insured party and so forth. If the daughter has no car insurance, and her father pays for it, she is still the insured party or policyholder.

Answer (score 2):

None of these are entirely correct, nor incorrect.  In many ways it depends on what sort of insurance we're talking about.

In common American English, those covered under medical insurance purchased by another are ***dependents***, even if they are not dependents in the typically (or the IRS) sense of the word.  It may be a spouse, even a spouse with a higher income and thus not a classic dependent.  It can be an elderly parent.  It is often children.

Those covered under auto insurance policies... this varies widely even in the United States.  Typically, an auto insurance policy would cover a vehicle, regardless of driver, though often if folk under a certain age (often 21) will be driving, it must be noted in the policy and generally incurs a slight cost increase.  However, your auto insurance policy will often cover some liability for the policyholder(s) even driving other vehicles, and will cover damage costs for the insured vehicle even if someone else is driving it (very confusing).  At any rate, it's often referred to as a ***covered individual*** when dealing with how the policy covers people rather than cars.

Life insurance has ***beneficiaries***.  These are the people who will receive the payout from the insurance policy if the policyholder dies. Obviously for life insurance, the insured is never a beneficiary of their own policy.  However, for disability insurance, the covered AND other people can be listed as beneficiaries.

Comment: As for 'co-insured', for some types of insurance (auto, home) in the US, you can have multiple or joint policyholders.  This isn't uncommon at all.  Typically for homeowners insurance, if two people are listed on the deed or mortgage of the home, they are often both listed as policyholders because they have an equal stake in the property.

Answer (score 1):

In insurance, the insurance policy is a contract (generally a standard form contract) between the insurer and the insured, known as the policyholder, which determines the claims which the insurer is legally required to pay. In exchange for an initial payment, known as the premium, the insurer promises to pay for loss caused by perils covered under the policy language.

[the insured](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insurance_policy)

And in legal contexts, the insured party

So, insured party, the policyholder and insured party. If you pay for someone's insurance, the person is the policyholder, not you.

Your daughter is the policyholder and you are the wallet man. [joke]

Please note: This is not for medical insurance, which was not mentioned by the OP.

Comment: That's... not accurate.  My three children and my wife are all insured by my plan.  I am the policyholder, and they are covered dependents.  The person who takes out a policy is the policyholder.  A policy can cover other people - that doesn't make them policyholders.

Comment: Correct.  Some posters here are citing Wikipedia for their answers. Ouch!

Comment: It depends. Yes, if a parent has a plan and the kids are insured, they are covered dependents. That's true.  If a parent pays for a separate policy for a child, the child is the policyholder. That was really my point. In any case, the insured is right, whether dependent or not. The insured/s is the technical term.

Comment: @Jesse Williams Covered dependent is for health insurance. Not car insurance paid for by daddy. No mention was made of health insurance. In cars, additional covered parties: other drivers. But you are right about health insurance.

Comment: @Lambie, the OP didn't specify type of insurance.  That's why my answer below covers three cases.

Comment: @JesseWilliams That's right. But you say mine is not accurate, since medical insurance was not part of my answer, but it is technically right: even covered dependents are insureds.

Comment: @Lambie well, probably due to your assumption that the person is paying for a policy carried by the daughter.  I read the OP as the daughter being covered by insurance that the person is a carrier of.  Who actually pays for the policy isn't relevant.  I could have a policy and some stranger on the street could write checks to pay for it.  I would still be the policyholder and they would be nothing.  Since the daughter is covered, she's at least one party.  Which party isn't clear.

Comment: @JesseWilliams Who pays for the policy is relevant. If the father pays for the daughter's car or property insurance, she is still the policyholder, not him. For car insurance, it is not covered dependent. The OP did not make the distinction.

Comment: @Lambie we're waxing pedantic here, but your point is mine - who pays for the policy is absolutely irrelevant to the status of any policy participants.  The policy holder is the person whose name the policy is in, regardless of who pays.  Covered dependents, beneficiaries, or co-policy holders are those named in the policy contract, regardless of who pays. I could pay for your auto insurance, that has no bearing on who or what it covers. You keep assuming that the daughter is the policy holder, but there's nothing in the OP that would imply that.

Comment: My answer was generic, yours broke it down. But there is nothing at all "innacurate in my answer." It just does not cover everything.

Answer (score -4):

*Indemnitees* are those who receive indemnity in an insurance claim.

They can also be referred to as the *beneficiaries* of the policy.

Comment: Thank you! I think I go with *Beneficiary* which is more common than *Indemnitees*.

Comment: The "beneficiary" is different.  To finish the poster's sentence,  she would be an insurable interest. Def: a person has such an interest in property or in the life of a person if damage or destruction of the property or death of the person would expose him to pecuniary loss or liability. See INSURANCE.
Collins Dictionary of Law  Web.

Comment: This answer is not right. Beneficiary is wrong. That is for life insurance or other circumstances.

Comment: @Lambie Are you sure 'beneficiary' doesn't work for things like health insurance?

Comment: @Mitch A beneficiary would be for a life insurance policy. Not for a medical insurance policy.  A medical insurance policy has insureds. Covered dependents as was pointed out to me below.